# How do I addAll() items from a JAXB-generated collection to a simple ArrayList?

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to use JAXB to pull some elements from a large XML file (technically, it's [XTCE](http://www.omg.org/space/xtce/).)

JAXB generated a collection of objects for me. To get the subset of desired elements, I need to call:

```
List<SequenceEntryType> org.omg.space.xtce.EntryListType.getParameterRefEntryOrParameterSegmentRefEntryOrContainerRefEntry();
```

I'd like to fill up an

```
ArrayList<ParameterRefEntryType> integerParameters;
```

with the return value using the following code:

```
integerParameters.addAll(...); // calling long JAXB-generated function above
```

The *ParameterRefEntryType* derives from *SequenceEntryType*, so this should be kosher as long as I used an appropriate cast.

However, Eclipse reports:

"The method addAll(Collection < ? extends ParameterRefEntryType>) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (ParameterRefEntryType)."

I'm rusty on Java generic Collections, and I don't fully understand what's going on here. It seems like I need to redefine my ArrayList to only accept items of type ParameterRefEntryType. Can I use addAll() like this, or do I need to write my own loop to add the desired elements?

The alternative seems to be:

```
List<SequenceEntryType> entries = 
    entryList.getParameterRefEntryOrParameterSegmentRefEntryOrContainerRefEntry();
Iterator<SequenceEntryType> entryIterator = entries.iterator();
while (entryIterator.hasNext()) {
    SequenceEntryType currEntry = entryIterator.next();
    if (currEntry instanceof ParameterRefEntryType) {
        _integers.add(currEntry);
    }
}
```

If this method is necessary, I'll definitely consider using [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/).

Comment: Are you sure your bindings are correct?  You should be able to get JAXB to give you a list of the generated class representing your XML schema type.

Comment: Not positive, I need to research JAXB some more. For now, I just pointed it at the official XTCE schema document with no customization. The only accessor JAXB provides on the EntryListType class is the extremely long function name above. I think there should be a way to get an accessor to only those <SequenceEntry> nodes that are of type <ParameterRefEntry>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't give you hints about JAXB but this is a bit about collections:

You have:

```
1. ParameterRefEntryType extends SequenceEntryType
2. ArrayList<ParameterRefEntryType> integerParameters;
```

and now look at definiitions add and addAll:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
public boolean add(E e)
```

In your case E is ParameterRefEntryType

so integerParameters.addAll() can work only with ? extends ParameterRefEntryType it's mean that you can put there only elements ParameterRefEntryType and childrens

add() has similar requirement so if you want add this object you can do this manually, but you must cast your currEntry:

```
integerParameters.add((ParameterRefEntryType) currEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop can be written a bit shorter:

```
for(SequenceEntryType currEntry :
     entryList.getParameterRefEntryOrParameterSegmentRefEntryOrContainerRefEntry()) {

    if (currEntry instanceof ParameterRefEntryType) {
        _integers.add((ParameterRefEntryType)currEntry);
    }
}
```

Of course, it looks better if your method names are not so absurdly long.

smas already said why it does not work with `addAll` (the original list can contain elements which are not of type ParameterRefEntryType).

Comment: Thanks for the loop improvement. Yes indeed, the JAXB-generated names are too long. I'm going to refactor this.